# NSMutable array with 2 columns

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am new to objective C

I want to add in a NSMutableArray on each line 2 values ( i i , i j, i n)

I have this code:

UPDATE:
  I've decided to create 2 NSMutableArrays:

```
NSMutableArray *sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *second_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
@try {
        for (Table *table in Class_1]) 
        {
            NSMutableArray *second = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            for (id item in table.NSSET_DATAS)
            {
                [second addObject id];
            }
            [sections addObject:table.firstVal];
            [second_array addObject:second];

            // how to add the NSArray second?

        }
    }
@catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR IN SETLISTCONTENT");
    }
```

How to retrieve from position 5 both values from position 1 and the array?
I have error when doing this:

```
NSString value= [self.second_array  objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I have updated, please give your comment am i understand right??

Comment: what have you updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store both values in NSMutableDictionary add Dictionary in your NSMutableArray. You will get two values in every index..Example like this.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray allao]init];

NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[data setObject:first forKey:@"first"];
[data setObject:second forKey:@"second"];

//Add this to your array
[array addObject:data];
```

I hope it helpful for you...

Answer (score 0):

First thing you cannot add object in NSArray, if you want to add then take NSMutableArray.
Second thing if you want to add in mutablearray then use below api:-

```
[second addObjectsFromArray:sections];
```

here it is wrong, As in your one mutablearray you have one object which is also an mutablearray and then inside you have string. So extract like that below:-

```
NSString value= [self.second_array  objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *newArray=[self.second_array objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *value=[newArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",value);
```

Comment: I'll update my code. I ve decided to create 2 NSMutableArrays.Please take a look

Comment: i am not getting exactly what you wanted to achieve and what is your current problem??

Comment: You can add simply in mutable array using addObject api

Comment: I ve updated my code:) Can you take a look and tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: NSString *value= [self.second  objectAtIndex:0]; Try like this

Comment: I just found out the issue. The reason why my code was not working is because the self.second was nil. Thank you!

Comment: Oh ok and also i have updated some more code, what you wanted to achieve exactly. Please follow